# Problem with GWT Visualization Core Chart Package and SmartGWT

Tags: javascript, gwt, charts, smartgwt, google-visualization

I am using Smart GWT and gwt-visulisation charts together

If Smart GWT is loaded then the graph does not render.
 Alternatively, if you change

```
VisualizationUtils.loadVisualizationApi(onLoadCall back,"corechart");
```

to load

```
 VisualizationUtils.loadVisualizationApi(onLoadCall back,PieChart.Package);
```

then the chart renders.otherwise it does not render corechart

Please suggest me

Thanks

Comment: is there anyone to solve this problem?..........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to provide which PieChart you imported.

Most likely you are rendering the other PieChart (com.google.gwt.visualization.client.visualizations.PieChart)

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, the com.google.gwt.visualization.client.visualizations.* charts have been deprecated in favor of com.google.gwt.visualization.client.visualizations.corechart.*

I have blogged about this here:

http://tamsler.blogspot.com/2011/06/gwt-chart-tools-loading-new-corechart.html

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who might get stuck with this : 
The issue can be seen [here](http://code.google.com/p/smartgwt/issues/detail?id=405)

It was solved in the nightly version of smart-gwt around feb 2011 - so if you use smart-gwt 2.4 (Released Dec 2010) , you don't have it yet. Move to smart-gwt 2.5 and the problem should be solved.